# Google Map Api V2 not showing Map on device

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am running sample code that is provided on Google Map Documentation for Google Map Api v2.The Code run successfully but Map is not loaded on the Device. Only White Screen is Shown on the Device. I am using 2.3.6 version android device.

Please Help me to resolve the issue

Comment: you probably dont have the google map key. There are many tutorials & SO answers. Search

Comment: can u share the relevant code snippet ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but may be a solution (since the existing map APIs have been way to fat and complicated at least for my purposes): http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwlocate/ performs GPS/WLAN-based positioning and provides several service functions for showing/drawing on maps of different sources.

Comment: Have you applied the API key in `Manifest.xml` file by registering your application?

Answer (score 1):

Check if u have the map key for the package name u provided while creating the map key.
I was getting white map screen but i inserted map key of the package i was testing.
Then i created new project but used the previous map key hence getting white screen.

Always remember you have to use new map key for each package you create. Genereally people forget that thing..(atleast i forgot to generate new key for new package).

Hope this will solve ur problems.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using **release** SHA1 fingerprint for generating Google API Key. Since you're using Eclipse for **debugging** your application is signed using debug key. So, you should use debug key instead to generate Google API key.

As soon as your app will be ready for publishing - just switch to release key.